# Where to find gtx560Ti driver for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, drivers

I found in this nvidia link : http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-295.59-driver.html

It says Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver

Version:

295.59 Certified

Supported:

NVS 5400M

NVS 310

Quadro 410

GeForce GT 620M

GeForce GT 640M

GeForce GT 640M LE

GeForce GT 650M

GeForce GTX 660M

GeForce GTX 670M

GeForce GTX 675M

GeForce GTX 555

GeForce GTX 560 SE

GeForce GT 415

GeForce GTX 460 v2

Is that driver support for gtx560Ti?

If not ,where is the proper driver? (I don't want to use the driver in ubuntu settings)

Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this driver is supported for your graphics card.

What you see was `RELEASE HIGHLIGHT` and it was written

`Added support for the following GPUs:` following by your list. That means in that version they have added the support for the aforesaid products.

If you click on `supported products` tab of the page (the link you posted) your Graphics card is enlisted over there under 500 series.

A careful reading  sometime helps. :)